# Disabling Autocomplete In Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, autocomplete

The following notation no longer seems to disable autocomplete for text fields in Ionic:

`<ion-input autocomplete="off">`

`<ion-input autocomplete="false">`

`<ion-input autocomplete="nope">`

`IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false, autocomplete: 'off' }),`

`IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false, autocomplete: false }),`

Has anyone had any success getting this working with an alternative notation?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: I'll be honest, it, uh, just kind of quit happening. I just double checked our code base to be sure, but there is no code in there that should disable autocomplete but it's stopped autocompleting. Sorry I couldn't be of more help :P

Comment: Same problem in ionic 4